# Ionic 3 page.module.ts exports statement

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, ionic3

I just started with Ionic 3. And I am following the new page lazy loading guidelines.

Assume that I have a page called ControlPage. So in most of the tutorials I looked at, it was specified that I should add

```
exports: [
ControlPage
]
```

to the control.module.ts.

But I noticed that the pages load fine even without this part in the control.module.ts. So what is the real use of this statement? And why does my page loading work even if I don't use that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use latest `CLI` then you don't need that.

```
ionic generate page Control
```

This will create `control.module.ts` file by default and it has lazy loading enabled. It looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ControlPage } from './control';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ControlPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ControlPage),
   ],
})
export class ControlPageModule { }
```

Here is the [**official blog post**](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/) about it.